# Javascript syntax with functions

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm not sure what this means or how to word the question correctly.

In the first example I could put the variable before the function "numbers1.forEach(...)" but in the second example I could not "num.square()"?

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}

var numbers2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
forEach(numbers2, function(number) {
  sum += number;
});
console.log(sum);
// → 15

var numbers1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
numbers1.forEach(function(number) {
  sum += number;
});
console.log(sum);
// → 15
// this works!
```

But this does not work

```
var square = function(x) {
  return x * x;
};

var num = 12;
console.log(square(num));
// → 144

console.log(num.square());
// → TypeError: undefined is not a function (line 9)
// does not work?
```

Thanks!

Comment: `forEach` is a built-in method on `Array`s. `numbers1.forEach()` is calling a different method than `forEach(numbers2)`.

Comment: `forEach` is a method of `array` variables, while `square` is your own function and not a method of the `integer` variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax-wise, there's no "magic" happening here. You're describing two very different things.

In your first example, you're passing an `Array` to your own defined `forEach` method. In the second example, the `forEach` you're calling is actually a built-in method on `Array`s (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). If you changed *your* `forEach` to not invoke `action`, you'll see that yours breaks and the second one still works.

You can achieve this functionality yourself. You could add a function to `Number` to make your second example work (although this is not a recommended practice, as it could collide with future JavaScript features [and many other reasons] or break existing functionality):

```js
Number.prototype.square = function() {
      return this * this;
};

var num = 12;
var squared = num.square();

alert(squared);
```

Comment: @unobf: Agreed, I added a brief notice in my answer.

Comment: Ah thank you! I forgot about "built-in methods." Cleared up all my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The example with the array works because `Array` in JavaScript (ECMAScript5) defines a [forEach](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) function.

The example with the number doesn't work because `Number` doesn't define a `square` function. You can extend `Number` to include the square function like this:

```
Number.prototype.square = function(x) {
  return this * this;
};
```

Comment: Why submit in the first place if you know you are gonna edit it? Why not just wait with the initial submit?

Comment: I think you mean `Number.prototype.square`?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `forEach` function from your first example, it will still work, that is because the Array type has a builtin `forEach` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Alternatively try to change your `forEach` function to `each` and you will see that it will no longer work.

What you are trying to do is add a new method to an existing type. This is not good practice in JavaScript.